# Create subdirectory with the same name of files in the parent directory

Tags: bash

Suppose I have 10 files in a parent folder called `abc`

```
1fyr.pdb
1r0p.pdb
1r1w.pdb
1shy.pdb
1ssl.pdb
2g15.pdb
2rfn.pdb
2rfs.pdb
2wd1.pdb
2wgj.pdb
```

I want to create 10 different directories in the same folder with same 10 names in `abc` folder

Comment: You can't have a directory and a regular file with same names inside the same directory.

Comment: Thanks @Quasímodo, but imagine I want to create the directories without .pdb extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *; do
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
done
```

The `${file%.*}` construct removes the extension.

This is quite short, you could use it as one-liner: `for file in *; do mkdir "${file%.*}"; done`

Comment: It works!!! Thanks

Comment: You could add `*.pdb` to the forloop to be thorough, and add the the `-p` to `mkdir`.

Comment: Hi, now I want to copy certain lines from those .pdbfiles to another file with a new name into the same directories! Any leads? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! @Quasímodo I prepared a new question. Please look into it